# How to save images separately which are surrounded by box

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new in python. I want to save image  separately which I extracted through contours.
Thanks in advance.

region = []
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in range(len(contours)):
cnt = contours[i]

```
    # Calculate contour area and screen out small areas
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if (area < 80):
        continue

    # Find the smallest rectangle
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    print ("rect is: ")
    print (rect)

    # box is the coordinate of four points
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    # Computing height and width
    height = abs(box[0][1] - box[2][1])
    width = abs(box[0][0] - box[2][0])

    # According to the characteristics of the text, select those too thin rectangles, leaving flat ones.
    if (height > width * 3):
        continue

    region.append(box)

# Draw outline
for box in region:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Comment: A little bit unclear. Do you want to save each part of images where surrounded by a green box as a separate image?

Comment: yes I want to save each part of images which is surrounded by a green box

Answer (score 0):

You have the box coordinates for each contour already. All you have to do now is to crop these boxes out and store them as images.

Let the box coordinate be stored in the format: `box = [x, y, w, h]`
where, `(x, y)` is the coordinate of top left corner of the box, `w` is the width pf the box, and `h` is the height of the box.

Now to crop this box's image out and save it, use this code:

```
box_image = image[y : y+h, x: x+w]
cv2.imwrite("image_name.jpg", box_image)
```